# ¿Cómo sacar el máximo de la primer iteración de dos arreglos?

Tags: php, php7

Para poder ejemplificar y visualizar de forma más resumida ya que manejo información de la Base de Datos, tengo estos dos arreglos:

```
$arr1 = array(10,50,4,32);
$arr2 = array(30,22,45,27);
```

Y quiero sacar el máximo de su primer iteración por ejemplo en la primer iteración es 10 y 30, el máximo sería `30` y así sucesivamente, este es mi código:

```
      for ($i=0; $i < count($arr1); $i++) { 
            //yo aquí espero que en la primer iteración 
    //la variable $maximos contenga $maximos = [10,30];
//2da iteración que máximos sea $maximos = [50,22];
        array_push($maximos, $arr1[$i], $arr2[$i]);
    //1ra iteracion el máximoes 30
//2da iteracion el maximo es 50
            $max_arr = max($maximos);
        //guardar esos maximos en otro arreglo
            array_push($valores, $max_arr);
//$valores=[30,50...]; así hasta terminar las posiciones de los arreglos.

        }
        var_dump($valores);
```

Esta es mi salida:

> [30,30,45,45]

Cuando yo espero esta salida:

> [30,50,45,32];

Según mi lógica que no está nada bien, hago `array_push` para agregarle los dos valores en la primera iteración y de esos dos valores sacarle el máximo y agregarlo a otro arreglo, pero no funciona, gracias por cualquier ayuda.

Comment: Tu pregunta no es muy clara. ¿Quieres sacar `10` y `30` y meterlos en un nuevo arreglo? ¿O quieres sacar el mayor valor que haya entre los dos arreglos y meterlo en otro arreglo, o sea, tener un arregolo con un solo valor que sería `30`?

Comment: No, según tengo entendido que `max()` sirve para obtener el valor máximo dentro de un arreglo, entonces quiero agregar en un arreglo por ejmplo, 1ra iteración `$maximos = [10,30];` su maximos es `30`, 2da iteración $maximos=[20,22];` su máximo es 22, así sucesivamente y en otro arreglo ir guardando esos máximos, no se si me expliqué. :CCCC Para que el resultado esperado sea `$valores = [30,22,45,27]`.

Comment: No es del todo claro. ¿Quieres ir comparando los dos arrays por cada posición e ir sacando el máximo entre esas dos posiciones? Por favor pulsa en [edit]  y explica con un ejemplo más claro lo que  quieres hacer.

Comment: Ya la edité, comentando en las partes del código y la salida que espero y la salida que me arroja, no sé con qué otro ejemplo especificar mucho más, de ante mano muchas gracias.

Comment: Y sí, lo que comentas es lo que necesito realizar @A.Cedano.

Comment: Ya lo resolví, necesitaba inicializar el array `$maximos` vacio cada que entre al `for()`, gracias por molestarte en leer mi pregunta y una disculpa por mi ignorancia. :C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahora se entiende.

Puedes usar un `foreach` para leer uno de los arrays, recuperando el índice `$k`, a través del cual podrás llegar al valor del otro array para hacer la comparación con `max`

```
$arr1 = array(10,50,4,32);
$arr2 = array(30,22,45,27);
$maxValues=array();

foreach ($arr1 as $k=>$v) {
    $maxValues[]= max($v,$arr2[$k]);
} 
var_dump($maxValues);
```

**Salida:**

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  int(30)
  [1]=>
  int(50)
  [2]=>
  int(45)
  [3]=>
  int(32)
}
```

---

## Nota

Esto sólo funcionará cuando los dos arrays a comparar tengan la **misma longitud**.

Comment: Excelente me funcionó también de esta manera y sí, todos mis arreglos tienen la misma longitud, muchísimas gracias! :D